# Windows Live ID integration

Tags: internet-sites

I'm planning to use Windows Live ID integration in one of the SharePoint internet sites that I'm currently working on. I want to allow users to login to the website using their WLID. One requirement though is that they should be registered with WLID using a specific custom domain name.
Now if I configure WLID authentication in the SP farm, any WLID user will be able to sign in to the website, but I want to restrict this to WLID users of a specific domain, any one has any recommendations on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use [Wictor's post about Windows live authentication](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Visual-guide-to-Windows-Live-ID-authentication-with-SharePoint-2010-part-1.aspx) for integration? For restricting the users of sepcific domain, I would recommend using HttpModule to filter the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to restrict someone's access based on the domain name of the email address associated with the Windows Live ID, I do not believe you will be able to do this. Windows Live will return a claim with a unique identifier that, sadly, is not the user's email address.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647034/get-input-email-address-from-acs-when-using-liveid), this limitation is due to the Windows Live privacy policy.

The best you could possibly do would be to develop a custom login page, hosted in your environment, that would only allow a user to submit his/her credentials to validate against Windows Live if the inputted email address string ends in the domain name(s) you wish to allow. Even if you did that, though, there is no way you would be able to configure your Relying Party to *only* authorize users whose Windows Live IDs are associated with a particular domain.